# How did the native reptilians traverse levels?

Tags: published-adventures, traveller

CT-TTB, *The Traveller Book* contains two adventures.

(Spoilers ahead for the adventure "Shadows.")

> In "Shadows" there appears to be only one way built into the complex that one can descend/ascend: the "knobby cable" in locations 9+21. And we know the natives used it, because of the ascenders stored in location 21.
>
>  But ascending/descending that cable would seriously disturb the motion of the pendulum, which is presumably important? (See pattern inscribed below bob.) Is that really how the reptilians went up and down?
>
>  It seems really incongruous for a civilization that's mastered such technologies as stairs (see outside) and auto-targeting lasers (see premise of adventure) to make their priests shimmy up and down a cable, and in doing so make the cable do double duty.
>
>  Related: why the vertical shaft in locations 1+15? Did they somehow use that one to get up and down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears on p.140 in the Referee's notes:

> > Access from the interior level to the deep level by the aliens was by an elevator platform which travelled within the vertical shaft from 1 to 15. The fracture at 14 however, has made that elevator inoperable. Safety interlocks have since made the elevator almost undetectable, and adventurers will probably not discover it.

---

> As for the equipment in location 21 I believe it would be for use in an emergency should the 1+15 shaft elevator fail, such as the case in Shadows. But climbing the cable could conceivably be part of some ritual or ceremony instead.

Comment: My bad on the page #, I missed you were using CT-TTB, I referred to CT-DA01